# compile aidl in batch

Tags: android, aidl

I try to compile aidl files to java file so that I can import them in eclipse to correct the ugly red warnings. 
I succeeded to compile an aidl file. But something went wrong when I compiled them in batch.

```
boob@boob-virtual-machine:~/Workspace/jb-4.2/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os$ find -name 'I*.aidl' -exec aidl -I/home/boob/Workspace/jb-4.2/frameworks/base/core/java/ '{}' \;

./IVibratorService.aidl:20 interface IVibratorService should be declared in a file called android/os/IVibratorService.aidl.
```

why?

Comment: You need to follow the Java package rules. You're running `aidl` on ./IVibratorService.aidl but it needs to see it as `android/os/IVibratorService.aidl`. You should put it in a path like that and compile it from the appropriate directory.

Comment: Thank you. I make it with your comments